# Handling specific column datatypes in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pandas dataframe with category and datetime64[ns] types. When looking through the Spark datatypes in pyspark.sql.types I could not find any equivalent for categorical. Is there any good recommendation or a way of defining a custom datatype?

The datetime64[ns] type can only accept a LongType in the schema, and crashes with both DateType and TimestampType. For example

```
2016-06-06 07:15:32.112202 -> 1465197332112202000
```